# `git master` command and undoing the master branch update

Tags: git

so, I'm still very new to git and I was on a branch separate from master, trying to some stuff out and then just wanted to switch to the previous/working state of the app that's on the master. I ran `git master` command, which caused master to sync up with the branch I just left:

```
M   app/controllers/application_controller.rb
M   app/controllers/events_controller.rb
M   app/helpers/application_helper.rb
M   app/views/events/index.html.erb
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

`git log` does not display a record of this update. 
first of all, is `git [branch]` equivalent to `git checkout [branch]` and how do I switch to master without it updating? second, is there a quick way to undo this update?

Comment: `git master` is not any command that I know of. Switching branches does not create a new commit in the git log. To "undo", simply checkout the previous branch (quick way: `git checkout -`)

Comment: this is so weird. I was in master, then did `git checkout [another branch]`, made a small change in a file, then did `git checkout master`. and now this change is also present in master. why does it do that?

Comment: Uncommitted changes do not belong to any branch. They only live in the working tree. Switching branches will leave the changes in the working tree. That's how Git works.

Comment: oh ok, so commit changes to the branch before checking out and it only keeps those changes in the branch you're in?

Comment: Yes, once changes are committed, they are permanently associated with a branch's history. You can also `stash` them, if you are not ready to commit yet. You can re-apply the stash later.